# In ZK, How do I adjust UI component according to orientation of the mobile device?

Tags: java, android, iphone, zk

I'm using ZK6, and I would like to change my UI component according to orientation of the mobile device.

In ZK component reference : [Tablet Devices/Events/ClientInfoEvent](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Tablet_Devices/Events/OrientationEvent) , there is a `getOrientation()` method in `ClientInfoEvent`. <strike>However, I did not see this method in the class, nor could I find any information about this method</strike>. (see update)

Right now I am using this piece of code to adjust component size when device orientation changed.

```
@Override
public void doAfterCompose(Groupbox comp) throws Exception {
  super.doAfterCompose(comp);
  comp.addEventListener(Events.ON_CLIENT_INFO, new EventListener<ClientInfoEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(ClientInfoEvent event) throws Exception {
      getSelf().setHeight(event.getScreenHeight() + "px");
      getSelf().setWidth(event.getScreenWidth() + "px");
    }
  });
}
```

But I'm not quite satisfy with it because it require server to update the component, and I still don't know what orientation it is.

So, how do I know orientation ? and what is a better way to adjust component size according these information ?

I use android emulator to test, if that matters.

### UPDATE

I notice that `getOrientation()` are implement in version 6.5.0, which is not from a stable release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 6.5.0 has been released a while, I decide to answer this question.

Basically, `ClientInfoEvent` now provide information about orientation, and also 
device pixel ratio

so now we can write code like this :

```
@Override
public void doAfterCompose(Groupbox comp) throws Exception {
  super.doAfterCompose(comp);
  comp.addEventListener(Events.ON_CLIENT_INFO, new EventListener<ClientInfoEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(ClientInfoEvent event) throws Exception {
      if (event.isLandscape()) {
        // do things when landscape
      } else {
        // do other things else.
      }
    }
  });
}
```

For re-size component, I wrote some client side code to adjust widget width/height at client side, and use java code to ask server to update component if necessary.